# Antd locale is undefined

Tags: webpack, antd

I'm trying to add a LocaleProvider to my app to put the antd components in English (instead of the default Chinese). I followed the following instructions from https://ant.design/components/locale-provider/ :

```
import { LocaleProvider } from 'antd';
import enUS from 'antd/lib/locale-provider/en_US';

...

return <LocaleProvider locale={enUS}><App /></LocaleProvider>;
```

This however doesn't work: `enUS` is `undefined`. I have declared the Antd library as an external in my webpack config because I don't want to bundle the whole Antd library in my `app.js`, so I use a `<script>` tag in the `<head>`:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/antd/2.11.0/antd-with-locales.js"></script>
```

Relevant part of my Webpack configurarion:

```
externals: {
    "react": "React",
    "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
    "antd": "antd"
}
```

When I try the second approach described on the LocaleProvider documentation:

```
const { LocaleProvider, locales } = window.antd;

...

return <LocaleProvider locale={locales.en_US}><App /></LocaleProvider>;
```

It works and my application is translated. But I don't like the mixture of "import styles".

So, my question is: What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't the first method work? Is this because of adding `antd` to the externals of my webpack config and if so, how can I solve this?

Comment: did you check if there is a file in `/node_modules/antd/lib/locale-provider/en_US.js` ? also can you explain what do you mean with "adding antd to the externals of my webpack config", can you show the webpack config?

Comment: Yes, the file exists. Adding libraries to the webpack configuration is a common practice, check out https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html for documentation about it. I added the relevant part of it to my original post.

Answer (score 4):

It may be related to webpack and typescript?

Here is the workaround for it:

```
// Original code in doc which will not work
//
// import enUS from 'antd/lib/locale-provider/en_US';
// ReactDOM.render(
//    (<LocaleProvider locale={enUS}>
//         <DatePicker />
//     </LocaleProvider>),
// document.getElementById('root'));
//
//
// WORKAROUND (for TypeScript)
//
// import everything instead of the defaults.
import * as enUS from 'antd/lib/locale-provider/en_US';

// cast 'enUS' to 'any' so that it can be passed to LocalProvider
// If you use es6, you probably don't need this
const enUSLocale: any = enUS;

ReactDOM.render(
    (<LocaleProvider locale={enUSLocale}>
        <DatePicker />
    </LocaleProvider>),
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 2):

@Silox, here is my entire client/main.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import LocaleProvider from 'antd/lib/locale-provider';
import enUS from 'antd/lib/locale-provider/en_US';

import App from '/imports/components/app.js';

ReactDOM.render(
  <LocaleProvider locale={enUS}>
      <App />
  </LocaleProvider>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

This works and correctly renders without the chinese glyphs.

FWIW, the online doc was problematic for me because it is so much in chinese.  I had a little better luck with RTFC and the .md files in ./node_modules/antd/dist.

Comment: Hi @Mark Moore, I tried it like this but my enUS was undefined. Probably because I include antd in a different way in my app (with Webpack externals and including it in the <head>).

Comment: So, did this work for you @Silox?  If so, give me a bump up.  ;-)  If this did *not* work for you, let's figure out what's going on.

Comment: As you can read in my comment, sadly not. If I have some time, I'll try to set up a minimal "working" example.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
import LocaleProvider from 'antd/lib/locale-provider';
import enUS from 'antd/lib/locale-provider/en_US';

const { Content, Footer } = Layout;

const component = ({ children }) => (
  <LocaleProvider locale={enUS}>
    <Layout>
      <div>Hello work</div>
    </Layout>
  </LocaleProvider>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent more than 2 hours before I made it work on my side. Except the js import I had to configure webpack to decrease size of the bundle otherwise it was taking all the moment localization.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {ConnectedRouter} from 'react-router-redux'
import {LocaleProvider} from 'antd'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from 'store'
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import ruRU from 'antd/lib/locale-provider/ru_RU'
import App from 'containers/App'

const history = createHistory()
const store = configureStore(history)
const MOUNT_NODE = document.getElementById(`root`)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <LocaleProvider locale={ruRU}>
        <App/>
      </LocaleProvider>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  MOUNT_NODE
)
```

**webpack:**

```
...
plugins: [
  new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: `[name].css`,
    disable: false,
    allChunks: true
  }),
  new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /ru/)
],
resolve: {
  modules: [`client`, `node_modules`],
  extensions: [`.js`, `.jsx`],
  mainFields: [
    `browser`,
    `jsnext:main`,
    `main`
  ],
  alias: {moment: `moment/moment.js`}
}
...
```

**.babelc**

```
plugins": [
  "flow-react-proptypes",
  "styled-components",
  ["import", {"libraryName": "antd", "style": "css"}]
]
```